# QGIS interactive gradient editor - already available?

Tags: qgis, symbology, color-ramp

i have found several links on the "new interactive gradient editor" - which seems pretty interesting and comfortable !!! the features shown in a youtube video are promising, but i didn't find any reference information there ...
does anyone know whether or not this tool is already available ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's available for QGIS 2.14.2? I don't see it available for QGIS 2.14.1.

Comment: Just downloaded nightly build and 2.14.2 and nope, not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's targeted to version 2.16 - so not available in any public releases yet (unless you compile your own version!)

Comment: You could also have mentioned that you are the guy behind this great feature :)

Comment: cool tool ! ... thats kind of a pitty. it looks pretty fancy and handy as well. unfortunately i am not that kind of power-user who is able to "compile his own version"  on the fly - but would voluntieer for testing  (... a compiled version. anyway - that information about targeted version would have been useful as sub-text in the vdeo) thx